# Mysql -> How many columns can i have in users table ? should i store arrays or not?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database-design, serialization

i want to create a database for my users in which i will need to store around 50 different peace of info for each user.

example

Contact info will hv (address,phone,email,home_phone,etc...)
personal info will hv (name,last_name,dob,birth_city,work,etc...)
refree info ...(6 items)
etc

---

so i have many categories each contain at least 5-6 elements, so my question is

**Should i create a column for each item (will have about 50 field per user) or better to create one column for each category and use serialize to store array into that field (will have around 6 columns (each will hold array that will hold 6-7 items)  ?**

what would be best practice ? and in case i go for array choice should i make column type as text "cuz i wont be able to decide exact varchar size for all items" ?

Comment: It's normally a good idea to normalise repeated items into a separate table, and storing arrays or serialized data inevitably leads to problems

Comment: Using a good ORM and a good design, you'll lazily store your arrays in separate tables.

Answer (score 3):

I think serializing an array and storing that array in a relational database is a bad idea. For being able to employ the full power of a relational database including the bunch of possible sql queries to work on your data, you should think about a proper [relational database design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model) including one or more tables and relations between them. Think about [primary and foreign keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key) and [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). For more advice, you should post more info about your example.